# How do I apply different folder colors system-wide?

Tags: directory, 23.04

I want to be clear that I am not asking about how to use the folder color application. I found a set of folder icons in `usr/share/icons/Papirus/128x128/places` and wanted to know how to tell my system to use a certain set by default. I could spend an hour manually changing the icons of each folder I access regularly, but I feel like there has to be a better way. Also, new folders would still populate in the original style. How can I make ubuntu use a different color folder by default?